# Is it "all documents related to the transaction" or "all the documents related to the transaction"?

Tags: articles, definite-article

Would you tell me if I need to use *the* after *all* in the following sentence?

> Can you please send me all (**the**) documents related to the transaction
> tomorrow?

My intuition tells me that in this particular context *the* is optional. Please tell me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct, the '*the*' here is completely optional, and sentence is grammatically correct with or without it.